# center 2 divs with text

Tags: css

I try to center horizontally 2 divs and align these 2 divs between them. The problem comes when I put text of different size in each div. Here is the example:  http://jsfiddle.net/DgEcs/1/

Why does the red div moves down and how to solve it?
CSS:

```
.container{
    margin: 20px auto;
    height: 50px; line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center; /* to center red and blue */
    background: whiteSmoke;
}
.red{ 
    display:inline-block; /* to put it side by side */
    font-size: 10px;
    background:red;
}
.blue{ 
    display:inline-block; /* to put it side by side */
    font-size: 26px;
    background:blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container" >
    <div class="red"> aaaaaaa </div>
    <div class="blue"> bbbbbbb </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to the CSS of both `.red` and `.blue`

Comment: Ok, it works. Do you know why does it happen? and I tried before: vertical-align:center; and it did not work do you understand why?

Answer (score 2):

Just add `vertical-align:top`. Also you are able to optimize your css…

http://jsfiddle.net/DgEcs/4/

```
.container div {
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;
}

.red{ 
    font-size: 10px;
    background:red;
}

.blue{ 
    font-size: 26px;
    background:blue;
}
```

Now it should look like this:
[image: Screenshot taken from Chrome 26/OSX]

Comment: Ok, it works. Do you know why does it happen? and I tried before: vertical-align:center; and it did not work do you understand why?

Comment: Your fiddle is correct. But when you optimize the css : 1.the container does not get centered horizontally in the page 2 red and blue are nor centered between them. I don't understand your answer?

Comment: My jsfiddle is using the optimized styles and should work properly. Which browser you're using?

Comment: Your code in the fiddle is correct. I don't understand your code here, in this page, I don't see why do you think it is better?.

Comment: It is just a best practice because there is no need to duplicate styles. Imagine you're adding some more divs (.green, .yellow, .purple). If you are using inheritance you can save a lot of lines of code. For further informations i suggest you to read this: https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-css

Comment: Again, which browser (Version) you're using? Chrome 18, Firefox 20, Safari 6, etc.? In all versions i've tested it looks like the screenshot in my updated answer.

Comment: Your image and your fiddle is correct. But the problem is the code you put in this page and you say that optimize. I put it here: jsfiddle.net/t8tm9. I see it in Safari, Chrome, Firefox. If you get rid of the 0 auto and if you put the inline block in the container it does not center. I don't see how it optimizes?